# How to use user fields in the domain

Tags: odoo

I have a new model in which I have partner_ids many2many field. I have a menu for the new model. In the action I have written the below domain

```
<field name="domain">[('partner_ids','in',[uid.partner_id.id])]</field>
```

Error is getting. Please help.

I am getting the following error

> ```
> Uncaught Error: AttributeError: object has no attribute 'partner_id'
> http://localhost:8069/web/content/2371-b278aa7/web.assets_backend.js:205
> Traceback:
> Error: AttributeError: object has no attribute 'partner_id'
>     at F.__getattribute__ (http://localhost:8069/web/content/2371-b278aa7/web.assets_backend.js:205:7)
>     at Object.py.PY_getAttr (http://localhost:8069/web/content/2371-b278aa7/web.assets_backend.js:168:176)
>     at Object.py.evaluate (http://localhost:8069/web/content/2371-b278aa7/web.assets_backend.js:272:11)
>     at Object.py.evaluate (http://localhost:8069/web/content/2371-b278aa7/web.assets_backend.js:272:25)
>     at Object.py.evaluate (http://localhost:8069/web/content/2371-b278aa7/web.assets_backend.js:269:99)
>     at Object.py.evaluate (http://localhost:8069/web/content/2371-b278aa7/web.assets_backend.js:267:111)
>     at Object.py.evaluate (http://localhost:8069/web/content/2371-b278aa7/web.assets_backend.js:269:99)
>     at Object.py.eval (http://localhost:8069/web/content/2371-b278aa7/web.assets_backend.js:274:284)
>     at http://localhost:8069/web/content/2371-b278aa7/web.assets_backend.js:413:136
>     at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:8069/web/content/2370-746c4bf/web.assets_common.js:12:558)
>
>
>     class CustomAttachment(models.Model):
>     _inherit = 'custom.attachment'
>     _order = 'id desc'
>
>
>     partner_ids = fields.Many2many('res.partner','partner_attachment_rel','attach_id','partner_id',string="File Type")
>
> in xml
>
>     <record id="action_attchments_attendee_event" model="ir.actions.act_window">
>             <field name="name">Documents</field>
>             <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
>             <field name="res_model">custom.attachment</field>
>             <field name="view_type">form</field>
>             <field name="view_id" eval="False"/>
>             <!-- <field name="domain">[('partner_ids','in',[uid.partner_id.id])]</field> -->
>             <field name="context">{'create':False,'edit':False}</field>
>             <field name="help" type="html">
>                 <p class="o_view_nocontent_smiling_face">
>                     Create a new document
>                 </p>
>                 <p>
>                     Also you will find here all the related documents and download it by clicking on any individual document.
>                 </p>
>             </field>
>         </record>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`uid` is actually the current logged in users ID, what you need is the `user` object, which is available in the domain evaluation context. You can use the following:

```
<field name="domain">[('partner_ids','=',user.partner_id.id)]</field>
```

Comment: When I used this I got an error message as partner_id is not defined